# menu bar for themselves - only one in a line

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Working on my website can be configured for mobile, it is such that the menu is my category next to each other, I wish therefore that they have a line by itself so that you do not need to be careful what you check on.

You can see it here on my [website](http://www.absb.dk/).

CSS:

```
ul.menu {
  padding: 10px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #002855;
}
ul.menu li {
  width: 98px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="/">Forside</a></li>
    <li><a href="/mandskab/">Mandskab</a></li>
    <li><a href="/nyheder/">Nyheder</a></li>
    <li><a href="/koretojer/">Køretøjer</a></li>
    <li><a href="/galleri/">Galleri</a></li>
    <li><a href="/kontakt/">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="/login/">Log ind</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you'd simply change the `display:inline` to `display:block` inside your `ul.menu li` style in your mobile-targetted media query for your website to have each of the list elements on a new line.